# Where to source crimp dies for small uninsulated wire terminals

Tags: crimp

I have a Durite 0-703-51 crimp tool handle with replaceable dies, and have been searching everywhere for dies that go both smaller and larger. The die presently has 0.5-1.0 Econo/Superseal and 1.0-2.0 Super 2.8 compatibility. I have some small JST terminals for some 22 and 26 gauge wire. They are tiny and these crimp die jaws barely make contact.

I am looking for something that goes down to 0.1 or maybe 0.25, bu they don't seem to exist? What tools are being used to crimp these tiny terminals?

[image]

Comment: I have recently ordered this crimping tool because it handles a hole range of terminal sizes. Go look if it fits your requirements: https://www.engineertools-jp.com/pad111213

Answer (score 0):

Dies are generally not interchangeable between crimp handles, and not all crimp handles will have dies for all terminals produced for them. I tend to use crimp dies that can support D-sub for a lot of smaller things but not many replaceable die crimp handles have a D-sub die (which is one of the main reasons I chose the crimp handle that I did). Then there are, of course, crimp handles with non-replaceable die.

GreenLee PA2097 is the name of the die I use. It goes with the CrimpAll handle but if you give me relevant dimensions with a micrometer or caliper (not a rule), I can tell you if it will fit your handle. Critical dimensions include hole diameter, hole spacing, hole distance to the rear of the die, internal width of the jaws of the handle, and spacing between the edges of the *handle's* jaw when closed.

I've not actually seen a replaceable die for a ratcheted handle that small. There is the Engineer Inc. PA-09/20/21 but these are not ratcheted and I've been told they will not apply enough force to cold weld for long term reliability, though seems to be good enough for hobbiest purposes.

Comment: I've added a picture with dimensions. Let me know if that you have got works.

Comment: I'll have to get to work first.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot. Let me measure the die now before I forget again.

Comment: @JCollins I think they will fit. Measurements are near identical.

Comment: I've looked everywhere for that die but noone seems to sell it. Where did you find it?

Comment: @JCollins Digikey and Mouser do. Amazon sometimes has it.

Comment: Ah, all out of stock...

Comment: Looks very hard to get outside NA.

Comment: @JCollins Maybe. Go with the Engineer PA-09 then. Or with a d-sub ratchet crimper but they do vary in quality.